# A new badge? Acceptable?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I was going through the list of badges, I felt there may be a badge which will be awarded when a user has 250 (or more, whatever seems appropriate) of his answers accepted; it may be a hard-to-earn badge though.
What say? Is is possible?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable badge. You should suggest it at meta.stackoverflow instead of here, because it is not particular to ELU.

Comment: I wish there were no "badges" here. They just get in the way, and some of them are offensive. I would like to return the "Strunk and White" badge, for instance, but there's no way to do so, which shows that they are meaningless and useless. Like so many things on this site, "badges" are not well-suited to the topic. Good for boy scouts, maybe.

Comment: Hear, hear. Plaudits for the professor. We need less of this nonsense, not more.

Comment: It may be necessary to introduce a percentage as well. Of my 692 answers, it seems 268 have been accepted (just under 40%, which is about the same as Robusto).